# Ensure that word-1 is immediately before word-2

Tags: sparql

I have a phrase that I segment into words. Each word has a `ex:position` attribute that marks its order in the phrase like below:

```
 "Jack is painting and Mary is helping him"

 ex:phrase     ex:hasWord    ex:word-1 .
 ex:word-1     ex:label "Jack" .
 ex:word-1     ex:position "1"^^double .

 ex:phrase     ex:hasWord    ex:word-2 .
 ex:word-2     ex:label "is" .
 ex:word-2     :position "2"^^double .

 …
```

How can I make a query that insures that `ex:word-1` is immediately before `ex:word-2`.

```
      PREFIX ex: <http://www.w3.org/namespace/>
      select ?word1 ?word2
    {
      ?word1  ex:label ?label1 .
      ?word2  ex:label ?label2 .
    }
```

To restrict the distance between `ex:word-1` and `ex:word-2`, I tried

```
FILTER(ex:position(?position1, ?position2) < 2)
```

But I get:

> URI function {position} is not defined.

Comment: "right before" typically means "immediately before", but "is" appears twice in your sentence.  Can you be a bit more precise about the requirements?  I'm pretty sure that what you want is possible.

Comment: "I have a second question:" - then please ask that in a separate StackOverflow question. The reason is that you can only mark one answer as accepted, so if each of your sub-questions is best answered by a different SO answer, and you only mark one as accepted, it will not be clear any more to future visitors which answer actually solves the described question or problem.

Comment: I made two separate questions for more clarity (but actually it's one sparql query with 2 needs). Here i just ask about how to ensure that word1 should be immediately before word2.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "How can I make a query that insures that ex:word-1 is immediately before ex:word-2." By whatever segmenting process you used to generate the RDF, you by definition have that ex:word-2 immediately follows ex:word-1.  What is the actual question that you want an answer to?  Something like "Is the word 'is' followed by 'helping'?", or a query like "give me all pairs of adjacent words."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you almost had it. The following query will retrieve all the words that are inmediately before a given one in the text. The first filter is similar to what you tried (position of word 2 minus the position of word 1 is <2), but the difference should be positive (thus the second condition in the filter) :

```
PREFIX ex: <http://www.w3.org/namespace/>
      select ?word1 ?word2
    {
      ?word1  ex:label ?label1 .
      ?word1  ex:position ?p1 .
      ?word2  ex:label "label of the word you want" .
      ?word2  ex:position ?p2 .
      FILTER(((?p2 - ?p1)<2) && (?p2>?p1))
    }
```

I have been doing some tests in Twinkle, and the following is also allowed:

```
FILTER((?p2 - ?p1)=1)
```

which simplifies everything.
Finally, since you seem to be controlling what is asserted in the rdf, why don't you create a "ex:precedes" relationship? that way you could get your answer by doing something like:

```
select ?word1 ?word2
    {
      ?word1  ex:precedes ?word2 .
      ?word2  ex:label "your label" .
    }
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,thanks for your answer. I tried both of the query filters you proposed in 1- Virtuoso and this gives the error "sparql Non numeric argument(s) to arithmetic operation." and in 2- Allegrograph and this gives 0 results.

Comment: Are you sure your rdf has been validated? I had some trouble with what you posted. For example, you don't use the xsd prefix for assigning the double values. I validated both queries in [Twinkle](http://www.ldodds.com/projects/twinkle/) translating this your RDF to this [TTL file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16510488/test.ttl)